# Why are all my other 301 redirects working except these 2? (NOT a query string)

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect

I've got a list of over 100 redirects, nearly all of which seem to be working except for two. I'm using the common format for a htaccess 301 redirect:

```
redirect 301 /shop/category.cfm/wall-decals http://wallcandyarts.com/wall-decals.html
```

Near as I can tell, there's nothing wrong this one. The ones I'm having problems with are these two:

```
redirect 301 /shop/product.cfm/chalkboard-wall-panels http://wallcandyarts.com/chalkboard-decals/chalkboard-panels.html
redirect 301 /shop/category.cfm/chalkboard-decals http://wallcandyarts.com/chalkboard-decals.html
```

I've read about problems with query strings, but that's not the case here. I also saw when assembling this list of redirects that if the new path ended in "/" that it would cause it to get a similar result of what it's getting with the redirects above. For example, clicking http://www.wallcandyarts.com/shop/product.cfm/chalkboard-wall-panels will give you a "mashed" URL, and I don't know why. Any thoughts?

This is my first foray into anything this heavy with htaccess that didn't involve simply copy/paste, so forgive my ignorance here. Hoping to learn a lot.

Thanks!

UPDATE: Here is the entire htaccess. A lot of stuff that was there prior to me adding 301 directs. The code I added starts at line 181.

http://pastie.org/2371768

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the others working for you?  I've tried a handful, and each one that I've tried under `/shop` has thrown my browser under `wall-decals.html`.

`http://wallcandyarts.com/shop/product.cfm/seasons-designer-pillows` becomes `http://wallcandyarts.com/wall-decals.html/product.cfm/seasons-designer-pillows`.

The culprit is your last line:

```
redirect 301 /shop http://wallcandyarts.com/wall-decals.html
```

The `Redirect` directive is based on prefix matching.  As the documentation puts it:

```
Redirect /service http://foo2.bar.com/service
If the client requests http://myserver/service/foo.txt, it will be told to access http://foo2.bar.com/service/foo.txt instead.
```

This last rule catching all of `/shop` is clobbering every rule that's targeting something under `/shop`.  I'm not completely sure how the evaluation/priority is handled for `Redirect`, but `RedirectMatch` may be a better fit for your needs (or, at least, should be used for that last rule).

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/shop/product\.cfm/frames-wall-decals$ http://wallcandyarts.com/wall-decals/frames-decals.html
...
RedirectMatch 301 ^/shop/?$ http://wallcandyarts.com/wall-decals.html
```

Comment: Thanks, @Shane - I think that's the trick, but it looks as though server-side caching is turned on so I'm not seeing my updates in real-time. Waiting to hear back on that. Do you think I'll need to change every line to RedirectMatch and follow that format?

Comment: @Micah As far as what needs to change, the ones on parent directories - where you don't want to affect subdirectories of the location that you're redirecting (like `/shop`).

Comment: Weird thing, after applying the fix as mentioned, I tried the link in Chrome and it worked, and still would not work in Firefox. I cleared cache, still no luck. Going to say it's working, though. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, after actually clearing the browser cache properly (before I had only been shift+refreshing - does firefox have a single-page cache?) All working now. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should limit all of that code to your httpd.conf file, not htaccess. More of a security threat, since people can download it freely and use it against you. As for the failed redirects... do the destination pages not exist EXACTLY as quoted in the rules?

Comment: You never know with GoDaddy, but most Apache configurations prevent the download of `.htaccess`.  On the redirects; destination pages don't necessary need to exist to redirect to them.